# Date to another format: issue with the time in R

Tags: r, date, strptime

I have this kind of dates:

```
dates <- c("2018-09-01 00:48:30","2018-09-01 01:34:20", "2018-09-01 01:56:28", "2018-09-01 00:06:31", "2018-09-01 01:24:30", "2018-09-01 00:54:31")
```

That are in chr format. I would like to get dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss. So I tried

```
dates_2  <-as.character(as.Date(dates, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

But the result is

```
c("01/09/2018 00:00:00", "01/09/2018 00:00:00", "01/09/2018 00:00:00", 
"01/09/2018 00:00:00", "01/09/2018 00:00:00", "01/09/2018 00:00:00"
```

Where the hh:mm:ss did not go through... Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: Those are not dates but timestamps (date + time). Hence, after converting to date, the time information is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R's date type does not include time.  One option is to use `strptime` to first convert your text date times to `POSIXlt`, using an appropriate format mask.  Then, convert back to an output string using `strftime`, again using the mask you want.

```
x <- strptime(dates, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
output <- strftime(x, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

[1] "01/09/2018 00:48:30" "01/09/2018 01:34:20" "01/09/2018 01:56:28"
[4] "01/09/2018 00:06:31" "01/09/2018 01:24:30" "01/09/2018 00:54:31"
```

Comment: OR `as.character(strptime(dates, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: Thanks @A.Suliman. I actually had ´strptime(dates, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")´  at the beginning but it never game me the format I wanted. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Sorry - my mistake ;)